# How do I identify the process that owns a spurious dialog box?

Tags: windows-7

A spurious dialog box (informative, no?) keeps popping up on reboot.

What's an easy way to figure out what clearly-very-well-coded-piece-of-software threw it up there?  I've reduced the startup list to a minimal list to no avail.

[image: error box]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what was the program?

Comment: I'm also curious what the program was.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) has this feature in the form of a crosshair that you drag over any window or widget.  Click the "crosshair button" and drag to the window, then release.

[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks! I've been using Process Explorer for years and I never knew about that!

Answer (score 5):

In task manager, you should be able to right click it and select **Go to process**, which will open the processes tab and highlight the executable:

[image]

If that isn't helpful, [Winspector](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/Winspector.shtml) (basically Spy++) can give you a better idea:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Winspector](http://www.windows-spy.com/download/). Install it & run. Switch the **Window list**'s tab to **Process**. Then drag and drop the red "foresight" from the upper left corner of Winspector onto that dialog box. Winspector will highlight which process owns the message box.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already running [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (and if you aren't, [why not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey)?) then you could use its Window Spy utility to locate the culprit.

[image: Window Spy]

Comment: It doesn't you the process